# I have 3 rows per user, need to have one row (with 3 columns) per user instead

Tags: sql, pandas, union, common-table-expression

I'm creating a table with the earliest 3 purchases by customer along with the total count of purchases by said customer, using a CTE. I did this successfully with the query below, but it shows 3 rows for each user with a row for the first purchase date, 2nd purchase date, and 3rd purchase date as separate rows. I'm trying to show the 3 purchase dates as columns, with one row for each user, instead.

This table has hundreds of rows so I can't write the needed user IDs in the code. Any ideas? Is there a way to merge 3 CTEs or write code to spit out the earliest payment date, 2nd earliest, 3rd earliest, and total amount for the user as columns. Current code is below:

```sql
WITH cte_2
     AS (SELECT customer_id,
                payment_date,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY customer_id
                    ORDER BY payment_date ASC) AS purchase_number
         FROM   payment)
SELECT cte_2.customer_id,
       cte_2.payment_date,
       cte_2.purchase_number,
       Count(payment_id) AS total_payments
FROM   payment
       INNER JOIN cte_2
               ON payment.customer_id = cte_2.customer_id
WHERE  purchase_number <= 3
GROUP  BY cte_2.customer_id,
          cte_2.payment_date,
          purchase_number
ORDER  BY customer_id ASC
```

Current Output with above code:
[image: currentoutput]

Preferred Output:
[image: preferredoutput]

Comment: Can you give us a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. input / expected output?

Comment: Just added, thanks. Basically, is it possible to limit the row/purchase number WITHIN the CTE so I can just UNION them? is it possible to somehow list the purchase_number multiple times in SELECT?

Comment: Do you need an SQL solution or a pandas solution?

Comment: Thank you for the pandas solution! Is there any way you know how to tackle in SQL as well? Trying to figure out both.

Comment: Not my area of expertise, sorry. However, pivot exists in SQL as well: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Gotcha, much appreciated. Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 2):

if your sql product supports 'case when' then you can do it with:

```
WITH 
  cte_2
     AS (SELECT payment_id,
                Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    partition BY customer_id
                    ORDER BY payment_date ASC) AS purchase_number
         FROM   payment)
SELECT pmt.customer_id,
       Count(case when cte_2.purchase_number=1 then 1 else null end) as [First Payment],
       Count(case when cte_2.purchase_number=2 then 1 else null end) as [2nd Payment],
       Count(case when cte_2.purchase_number=3 then 1 else null end) as [3rd Payment],
       Count(pmt.payment_id) AS total_payments
FROM   payment pmt
       LEFT JOIN cte_2
       ON  pmt.payment_id=cte_2.payment_id
          and cte_2.purchase_number <= 3
GROUP  BY pmt.customer_id
ORDER  BY pmt.customer_id ASC
```

CTE simply assigns payment numbers for each payment, we then join the payments table to that CTE by payment id using left join, because an inner join would remove payments with payment number > 3 (but we want to count them)

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas you can use pivot:

```
df = df.set_index('customer_id')
pivot_df = df.pivot(columns='purchase_number', values='payment_dates')
# To improve readability of your columns you can add a prefix:
pivot_df = pivot_df.add_prefix('payment_') 
pivot_df.merge(df['total_payments'], left_index=True, right_index=True).drop_duplicates()
```

When using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customer_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3],
    'payment_dates':['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-01'],
    'purchase_number':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1], 
    'total_payments':[4,4,4,26,26,26,1]})
```

Our result is:

```
                payment_1   payment_2   payment_3   total_payments
customer_id             
1               2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03  4
2               2021-01-04  2021-01-05  2021-01-06  26
3               2021-01-01  NaN         NaN         1
```